# Can a SOAP fault happen client side?

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap

I have application that interfaces with a third party web service.  In my error log I occasionaly see a soap fault:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>68A4371:117259187 - Error: Invalid interval in timestamp</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've contacted the third party and they claim my service request doesn't show up in their logs and that the error is happening on my side.

**My Question: Is it possible to have a soap fault on the client side?**

Extra Info:
My client side code is in VB.NET and we added a service reference to the third party service.  We build the Custom binding to connect to the service in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a typical vendor - they are fobbing you off because the support person is an idiot and they have no idea how to solve the problem.

It is not possible for your client to generate a [soap fault](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383507) all by itself. It must come from the server.

If there was something wrong with your request the fault code would say *soap:Client* (rather than *soap:Server*) and in that instance you would have to do something to fix it.

The problem here is that the service programmer has added a fault string to the fault which is basically meaningless -

> 68A4371:117259187 - Error: Invalid interval in timestamp

What are you supposed to do with this information? What compensating action do they expect you to take as a result of this?

From the spec:

> The faultstring element is intended to provide a human readable
>   explanation of the fault and is not intended for algorithmic
>   processing. The faultstring element is similar to the 'Reason-Phrase'
>   defined by HTTP (see [5], section 6.1). It MUST be present in a SOAP
>   Fault element and SHOULD provide at least some information explaining
>   the nature of the fault.

I guess they assumed that the customer would just call up like you did and that the code would mean something to some junior support person.

I would go back to them again and tell them to sort it out.

Comment: Thank you Tom.  I will get back with them.